# Locate Installation files for Preinstallation of SharePoint Server 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, sharepoint-server

Goal:
Install SharePoint Server 2013

Problem:
I cannot find the recommended link to download the files of:

- Micosoft Information Protection and Control Client (MSIPC)
- Internet Information Services (IIS) 7.0 or hight, with ASP.net v4.0 in the list of IIS Web Server
- IIS 6 Management COnpatibility component to install

Information:
- Before doing installation of Windows Server I need application before entering installation of SharePoint Server 2013.

[image]

Comment: At least the IIS parts can be added as server roles

Comment: What link can you recommend me to use?

Comment: Depends on what server version you are using, for 2012 http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/installing-iis-8-on-windows-server-2012